# where to find the best Truffle configuration?

Tags: solidity, truffle

Unable to understand a working configuration to deploy to Goerli.
I've tried a few but the migration remains pending and after 750 sec is aborted.

My current config is:

```
goerli: {
networkCheckTimeout:10000,
provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic,'wss://goerli.infura.io/ws/v3/'+process.env.INFURA_KEY),
network_id: 5,
networkCheckTimeout: 1000000,
timeoutBlocks: 2000,
skipDryRun: true,
gasPrice:0,
gas:0,
maxFeePerGas:2500000001,
maxPriorityFeePerGas:2500000001,
confirmations:0,
websockets:false,
setTimeout:5000000000

         }
```

impossible to set EIP-1559 too, please help !

Comment: Why are you using the websocket (wss) infura rpc? Maybe this can be the issue

Comment: I've always used this to connect. Why are you blaming on infura wss? Anyway today I've tried http rpx as well with the same result :(